# Class activation map offset

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to get class activation maps for my EfficientNet classifier. I am using Keras (not Tensorflow Keras) and this is the code I am using for my EfficientNet: https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet

The class activation map implementation is quite simple:

```
    class_weights = model.layers[-1].get_weights()[0]
    conv_output = model.get_layer(name_last_conv)
    get_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [conv_output.output, model.layers[-1].output])
    [conv_outputs, predictions] = get_output([input2model])
    conv_outputs = conv_outputs[0, :, :, :]

    # Create the class activation map
    cam = np.zeros(dtype=np.float32, shape=conv_outputs.shape[0:2])
    target_class = 1
    for i, w in enumerate(class_weights[:, target_class]):
        cam += w*conv_outputs[:, :, i]
```

My problem is that the CAM is offset from the region that actually fires the detection. I used saliency maps and I get the region I was expecting so I'm guessing something is not right with CAM.

My guess is the upsampling from the 32x32 activation map to the actual 1024x1024 image should be done in a different way to account for the padding pooling, but I can't seem to get this right. Is there any way to do this?

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the xdeep library

Comment: That library will not work with my Keras code. I get the error: Model has no attribute 'eval'